# Cloud_firestore firestore not working in release mode

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When trying to retrieve data from firestore in **release mode** but it is not working,
I can send and get data in **debug mode** without any warning.

- I have added Internet permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- And I have added SHA certificate fingerprints (SHA-1).

Firestore Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 7, 19);
    }
  }
}
```

Packages added :

```
  firebase_core: ^1.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.0
```

Comment: Hi. I came across this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7406#issuecomment-1000994433), it says " Go to https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android and then follow this section -Configure signing in gradle, add these two line to buildtypes in release: minifyEnabled false, shrinkResources false and then check if it works"

Answer (score 2):

- I removed the build files in the android folder.
- I added SHA certificate fingerprints (**release and build**).
- also changed `signingConfig` in build.gradle to `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`

now its works in debug and release mode